# Background property of DataGridRow is wrong

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid, triggers, styles

I've got a WPF application that uses a `DataGrid` control and is used by police officers in police cars.  I use merged dictionaries to implement Day and Night "modes", where the color palette changes when you toggle the program between the two.  The application gathers data from special sensors my company makes and displays it for the officer(s).

The `DataGrid` in question is behaving oddly.  It is initially empty when the program first starts.  As data is collected, rows are added to the `DataGrid`.  When you start the program, it is initially in Day mode.  The problem is that the background of the first row does not change to the night mode color for the control.  It stays white, which is the day mode color.  If you toggle back and forth between day mode and night mode, it stays white.

This is different from any rows that are added to the `DataGrid` after that one, which have the right color and switch back and forth between the colors properly.

Here's the style I've defined in my App.xaml for the `DataGridRow` class:

```
<Application x:Class="MyApplication.App"
     . . .>

    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MyApplication;component/DayTime.xaml" />

                <ResourceDictionary>
                    . . .
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush"     Value="{DynamicResource DataBorder}" />
                    <Setter Property="Background"      Value="{DynamicResource DataBackground}" />
                    <Setter Property="Foreground"      Value="{DynamicResource DataForeground}" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background"  Value="{DynamicResource DataBackground}" />
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource DataBorderFocused}" />
                        <Setter Property="Foreground"  Value="{DynamicResource DataForeground}" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background"  Value="{DynamicResource DataBackground}" />
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource DataBorderFocused}" />
                        <Setter Property="Foreground"  Value="{DynamicResource DataForeground}" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background"  Value="{DynamicResource DataBackgroundSelected}" />
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource DataBorderSelected}" />
                        <Setter Property="Foreground"  Value="{DynamicResource DataForegroundSelected}" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
            . . .
                </ResourceDictionary>
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

When I run Snoop on the program and drill down to the `DataGridRow` in question, the `Background` property's value is white (#FFFFFFFF) and the Value Source for it is set to "DefaultStyle".  This doesn't seem to be the style I've defined, though, as it doesn't change when I toggle to day mode & back to white.  I think it's the default style defined by Microsoft and it's not using my style at all.  But only on the first row inserted into the `DataGrid` if it was initially empty.

For subsequent rows, the Value Source column reads "ParentTemplate".  This must be my style as the background colors do change properly as you toggle night mode.

How do I fix this so that every row in the `DataGrid` is correct?

EDIT:

In the interests of completeness, here's the style used by the `DataGrid` control, in case it helps.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
    <Setter Property="Background"                    Value="{DynamicResource DataBackground}" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground"                    Value="{DynamicResource TextForeground}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush"                   Value="{DynamicResource DataBorder}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness"               Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="RowDetailsVisibilityMode"      Value="VisibleWhenSelected" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode"      Value="Both" />
    <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled"        Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
                <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="DG_ScrollViewer" Focusable="false">
                        <ScrollViewer.Template>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Button Command="{x:Static DataGrid.SelectAllCommand}"
                                            Focusable="false"
                                            Style="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=DataGridSelectAllButtonStyle, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type DataGrid}}}"
                                            Visibility="{Binding HeadersVisibility, ConverterParameter={x:Static DataGridHeadersVisibility.All}, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.HeadersVisibilityConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"
                                            Width="{Binding CellsPanelHorizontalOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" />
                                    <DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter Grid.Column="1"
                                                                    x:Name="PART_ColumnHeadersPresenter"
                                                                    Visibility="{Binding HeadersVisibility, ConverterParameter={x:Static DataGridHeadersVisibility.Column}, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.HeadersVisibilityConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" />
                                    <ScrollContentPresenter x:Name="PART_ScrollContentPresenter"
                                                            CanContentScroll="{TemplateBinding CanContentScroll}"
                                                            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                                            Grid.Row="1" />
                                    <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar"
                                               Grid.Column="2"
                                               Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}"
                                               Orientation="Vertical"
                                               Grid.Row="1"
                                               Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}"
                                               Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                               ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}"
                                               MinWidth="45" Width="50" />
                                    <Grid Grid.Column="1"
                                          Grid.Row="2">
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding NonFrozenColumnsViewportHorizontalOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar"
                                                   Grid.Column="1"
                                                   Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}"
                                                   Orientation="Horizontal"
                                                   Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"
                                                   Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                                   ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}" />
                                    </Grid>
                                </Grid>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </ScrollViewer.Template>
                        <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsGrouping" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

EDIT:

As an expermient, I added this member variable to the code-behind of the window with the issue:

```
private static Style dataGridRowStyle = null;
```

Then I added this code to the constructor of my window:

```
if ( dataGridRowStyle == null ) {
    dataGridRowStyle = FindResource( typeof( DataGridRow ) ) as Style;
    MyGrid.RowStyle = dataGridRowStyle;
}
```

By doing this, I saw that every row added to the `DataGrid` had the original default style.  This also happended when I moved the above code to the `Loaded` event handler.

Next, I removed the above code and added an x:Key attribute to the `Style` definition in the app.xaml file.  I then added this attribute to the definition of the `DataGrid` control:

```
RowStyle={DynamicResource MyDataGridRowStyle}
```

Now every row has my style.  Which is great, but I thought that declaring my style with the `TargetType` attribute only was enough to get it to be applied to all rows.  Why didn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much head scratching, heartache, and web searching, I finally figured out what was going on in my program.

My program uses merged dictionaries to implement the day and night modes.  It turns out that the merged dictionaries were the cause of the problem, as explained [in this tutorial](http://wpftutorial.net/MergedDictionaryPerformance.html).

The fix is to put a default style in the root dictionary.  Actually, my code had all of the templates in a resource dictionary inside of the  tag. I moved them up a level and now WPF finds my default templates on the first row and every row.